# Movie where people rented empty bodies to travel

Tags: story-identification, movie, mind-uploading

I watched this movie when I was a kid. It's been more around 15 - 20 years since I watched and it suddenly popped in my mind.

It was highly possibly made during 90s. It was set in the future where people were transmitting their conscience into empty bodies they rented at their destination via a company instead of physically travelling there. I remember it as their original bodies were stored in the company facilities during their away time.

As I remember, the lead role was a businessman who got mixed in a criminal event because of body swapping.

Another hint is there was no gender restriction so a man could rent a female body and vice versa.

Also there was a thin string like tool which they used to cut stuff.

**Country of origin:** Hollywood possibly. Setting was set in USA as I remember.

**Protagonist:** As I remember, he was a businessman using this method to travel for business. Method is very common in the setting of movie.

**Scene details:** There are two scenes I vaguely remember:

- Lead role and a 'female body' was having sex and there was a dialog about 'singing nipples' ( That kinda stuff caught my attention probably due to my age. Also I watched it dubbed in my native language so original line may not be exactly that but translates to that).
- Lead role met the original 'consciousness' of that 'female body' in another place and time when 'she' was in another body. They recognized each other by the 'singing nipples' anecdote and then got caught by bad guys.
- Someone lost a few fingers while they were trying to cut the string which bind them and using that string like device to escape the bad guys but didn't care since it was a 'rental body'

Comment: It's obviously not the answer, but this is also the premise of the 1960s novel _Mindswap_ by Robert Sheckley.

Comment: You want to read _[Kiln People](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiln_People)_ by David Brin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably [XChange (2001)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0242150/).

[image: picture of cover]

Not much information to be found.

Imdb synopsis:

> In the near future, a company called Xchange owns a mind transference
>   technology that enables instantaneous travel by swapping bodies with
>   someone at the destination. A member of the privileged corporate class
>   ("Corpie") Xchanging for the first time unwittingly switches bodies
>   with a terrorist. Forced to hide in a limited life span cloned body
>   with just 2 days remaining, he races against time to stop the
>   terrorist and regain his body.

There is a reference to molecule-thick cutting wire in an imdb user review.

Trailer [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFrgDp8xzhs)

Full movie also on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jm6bZRW59mw)

In the full movie, a brief scan reveals:

- Reference to "singing nipples" at 0:26:50
- Finger cut off at 1:29:40